# how to reload a specific element with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I just wat to know how I can reload a specific element or div with javascript code.

div:

```html
<div id="profile_img">
   <figure>
      <img id="holla" src="avatar.gif"/>
   </figure>
</div>
```

hope you will help . I really need it . Thank you

Comment: How was that div originally created to the document?

Comment: means? can you please elaborate

Comment: What are you trying to "reload"? The image? Are you trying to add a new image?

Comment: Where did the div came from? Is it a part of a static page or did you create it with JS?

Comment: yes i want to reload the image

Comment: yes the div is the part of the html document itself

Comment: Why didn't you simply just say you want reload the image in your question ..? That would had been a clear question, an unspecified "_specific element_" and `div` are confusing.

Comment: i am very sorry if you found it confusing but i thpounght the image was in the div so i could just reload the div. BTW sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set the source of  an image in JS:

`document.getElementById("holla").src = "avatar.gif";`

```js
function refresh() {
document.getElementById("holla").src = "avatar.gif";
}
```

```html
<div id="profile_img">
   <figure>
      <img id="holla" src="avatar.gif"/>
   </figure>
</div>
<button onclick="refresh();">Refresh Image</button>
```

Comment: i think it is not working for me i am still having to reload the whole page to refresh the image. can you please suggest anything else

Comment: ok this snippet i have to put in the function and then call the function itself like: function reload() {
    document.getElementById("holla").src = document.getElementById("holla").src;


}
reload()

Comment: i am sorry my friend but it is not working i have tried it

Comment: i am updating the image

Comment: which url are you taking about the url to the image file??

Comment: @SenseofScience I mean.. does the "avatar.gif" remain "avatar.gif" or does it change to "avatar-2.gif"?

Comment: actually it is a little complicated let me explain my web site is actually a web site with login/signup mechanism and the default profile image is avatar.gif but when the user is signing up he/she can upload his image to the cloud and i am am further fetching that image from cloud but when the user is logging out i want the image to change back to the avatar.gif but it is not happening and i am having to reload the whole page to update the source

Comment: @SenseofScience so.. you want to change the source to "avatar.gif", instead of reloading?

Comment: actually yes i want to but always when an event like login/ signup or logout occurs. Can you please help me with that

Comment: BTW this line in your snippet does not do anything it is just changing the source    : document.getElementById("holla").src = "avatar.gif" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);    so you can remove it by edit 

Comment: @SenseofScience I know, that was to remove cache, but it is no longer needed so ill remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reload from server then you can do ajax call and set the response to that div.
document.getElementById('holla').innerHTML = this.responseText;

Comment: actually i am new to web development so can you tell what do you mean by ajax. my image is stored in firebase storage

Answer (score 1):

You must have some mechanism  to load the image. Ajax call will load the image asynchronously.

```
// Create an XMLHttpRequest object
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Define a callback function
xhttp.onload = function() {
  //you get response back from server in responseText.
  document.getElementById('holla').innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
// Send a request
xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt");// path to file
xhttp.send();
```